Lectura incorrecta números decimales en CSV
Una macro en Word con VBA lee mediante ADO un fichero CSV separado por comas con valores numéricos decimales separados por punto. Cuando cargo el recordset, me separa correctamente las columnas de cada campo pero cuando lee un vaor numérico con decimales (delimitado por punto) no me lo reconoce como tal.
Por ejemplo, una fila del csv es:
campo1,campo2,campo3,300000.00,campo5
La conexión que utilizo:
connExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & sRutaCSV & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"";"

la consulta SQL es:
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & sFileCSV & " WHERE CAMPO1 = " & txtCampo1    
rst.Open sSQL, connExcel, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

el valor devuelto para rst!Campo4 es 30000000, cuando debería ser 300.000,00
Gracias y un saludo!

el decimal esta separado por una coma, y eso no lo entiende tu sistema.. tenes que leerlo como string, y luego cambiar los puntos por nada, y la coma por un punto...

Hola @gbianchi La parte decimal del numero está separada por punto en el fichero CSV (300000.00) y los campos están separados por coma

ah lo entendi mal, perdon...

El problema que estás experimentando es de configuración regional justo en el equipo donde esta el ACE.OLEDB
Los valores numéricos en el CSV que están separados por punto pueden ser interpretados incorrectamente como enteros si el formato regional de tu sistema no coincide con el formato del CSV.
Asegúrate de que la configuración regional de tu sistema esté configurada para interpretar el punto (.) como separador decimal.
Ojo, esta modificación puede interferir en otros sistemas que ya tengas resuelto ese problema; sin embargo, si estás utilizando en ese mismo PC para abrir hojas de cálculo etc., puedes afectar la operativa, si esto último se cumple entonces deberas transformar registro por registro para cargarlo.
Esta seria la forma manual:

Sub LeerCSVManual()
    Dim sRutaCSV As String
    Dim sFileCSV As String
    Dim sLinea As String
    Dim vCampos As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rst As Object

    sRutaCSV = "C:\ruta\al\archivo\"
    sFileCSV = "archivo.csv"

    ' Creaas aqui un recordset manualmente
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rst.Fields.Append "Campo1", adVarChar, 255
    rst.Fields.Append "Campo2", adVarChar, 255
    rst.Fields.Append "Campo3", adVarChar, 255
    rst.Fields.Append "Campo4", adDouble
    rst.Fields.Append "Campo5", adVarChar, 255
    rst.Open

    ' Abres el archivo CSV
    Open sRutaCSV & sFileCSV For Input As #1

    ' Lees línea por línea 
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sLinea
        vCampos = Split(sLinea, ",")
        
        ' Agregas una nueva fila al recordset
        rst.AddNew
        For i = LBound(vCampos) To UBound(vCampos)
            ' OJO AQUI -> Si el campo es numérico, convertirlo manualmente
            If IsNumeric(vCampos(i)) Then
                rst.Fields(i).Value = CDbl(vCampos(i))
            Else
                rst.Fields(i).Value = vCampos(i)
            End If
        Next i
        rst.Update
    Loop

    ' Cerrar el archivo
    Close #1

    ' Ejemplo de acceso a los datos en el recordset
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        Debug.Print rst!Campo4 ' Mostrar el valor de Campo4
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' Cerrar el recordset
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub


